# Animate opacity in jQuery leaves ghost elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

When I animate the opacity of some elements, it seems like the animation doesn't always finish.  The result on my tooltips is as shown (to replicate, wobble your mouse back and forth over the divs):

[image]

Boxes 1 and 2 still have ghost elements over them.

Here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbnail").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".tooltip").animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: '105%'
        }, 200, 'swing', false);
        $(this).find(".label").stop(false, true).fadeIn(2); 
    },function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".tooltip").animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: '100%'
        }, 200, 'swing', false);
        $(this).find(".label").stop().fadeOut();
    });

    $(".label").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).find('h3 a').attr('href');
        window.location.href = url;

    })
});
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qu7Tu/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your animations are trying to start again before they complete. One solution to this would be to add `stop()` before each of the animation calls to stop the current animation before starting a new one. For example:

```
$(this).parent().find(".tooltip").stop().animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: '100%'
        }, 200, 'swing', false);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qu7Tu/1/

---

## EDIT

This seems to be a rendering issue in Chrome (opacity is shown as 0 in the Chrome inspector, and this bug doesn't exist in Firefox).

One solution seems to be setting the `-webkit-backface-visibility` CSS property to `hidden` for the tooltip, which solves the issue in chrome. Sorry but I an unable to accompany this fix with an explanation :)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qu7Tu/2/

Comment: wow that is strange. I only get the ghosts if I scroll down. let me investigate further.

Comment: Its **really** strange!

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is actually a rendering bug. With a ghost showing, chrome dev tools shows opacity at exactly 0; manually resetting to 0 makes it disappear. If you comment out the simultaneous animation of 'top', the problem goes away. Looks like animating 'opacity' and 'top' together is buggy.

Comment: agreed - thats what I discovered as well. Seems to work fine in firefox.

Comment: If either of you add that as an answer I'll mark it right.  Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Actually I seemed to have found a solution

Comment: Wo - you, sir, are a genius.  Thanks so much, really appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem! I hope a fix for this comes out soon